# Proper way to update model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-syncdb

I keep modifying my model in Django.  However after I do it I have to go into the database, delete the table manually and then `manage.py syncdb`.  I tried `manage.py reset <<app_name>>` but it doesn't drop then reinstall the model with the new fields.  What is the proper way to do this or is the best way to go into the database, delete, then syncdb?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django workflow when modifying models frequently?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497654/django-workflow-when-modifying-models-frequently)

Comment: Use south: south.aeracode.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you describe is explicitly mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb):

> syncdb will only create tables for models which have not yet been
>   installed. It will never issue ALTER TABLE statements to match changes
>   made to a model class after installation. Changes to model classes and
>   database schemas often involve some form of ambiguity and, in those
>   cases, Django would have to guess at the correct changes to make.
>   There is a risk that critical data would be lost in the process.

What you are after is a tool for database migrations and that [is a large problem mostly solved](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2009/nov/6/large-problems-database-migrations/) ;-)

So yes, as Marcin said, your are looking for [South](http://south.aeracode.org).
Alternatively you could try [Nashvegas](http://paltman.github.com/nashvegas/) and for small changes even [`sql_diff`](http://packages.python.org/django-extensions/sqldiff.html) which is part of [`django-extensions`](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) is a viable option.